# check if checkbox is checked in SPD workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

I have created an infopath form and published it as SharePoint list.

the form contains 30 checkboxes
 I need to send email by a workflow, the email should contain the value of the checkbox.

Is there any way the loop over these 30 checkboxes and see if some of them are checked.

logic is

```
foreach (checkbox in all checkboxes)
           if(checkbox is checked)
              send email(checkbox)
```

Comment: Are you using SP 2010 workflow?

Answer (score 1):

There is no looping activity in 2010. There is nothing stopping you from setting these all up individually, other than it is time consuming and a pain if the workflow needs to be migrated to another environment.

You'd simply do If CheckBoxField1 = Yes, email action. You'd need to do that 30 times. If it is a simple mailer, you could use an event receiver and do it in a much cleaner manner.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010, There is no loop statement.

In my workflow, when ever checkbox column value is checked then I should send auto-generated email.

I have taken a variable to store the HTML code, when condition reaches it should send email.

So, for 30 check boxes you try to create `Else-If Statement(s)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SP2010 workflow:

Check this [link](http://sharepointgypsy.blogspot.com/2011/11/create-for-each-loop-for-workflows.html)

Or if you are using 2013 workflow, then you can use the loop condition to Loop through the checkboxes and check if it is "checked".

Comment: yes 2010, to be able to send extern email

Comment: He doesn't want to loop over all items in the list, but all fields in the item.